# FFMPEG: Converting WAV to MP4 with filter loops forever

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using the following basic `ffmpeg` commend to convert a WAV file to an MP4.

`ffmpeg -i response.wav -s 1980x1080 -c:a aac -b:a 128k aNewVideo.mp4`

This is great, however I'd like to include a black background on the mp4 file, and as it stands this doesn't add ANY background (see below).

[image]

I have tried to include the following filter to add this background, which works, however it loops forever, and when I stop it manually I get a file which is hours long with the first 20 seconds or so being my original audio.

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=5 -i response.wav -s 1980x1080 -c:a aac -b:a 128k aNewVideo.mp4`

How can I add this black background without running into this infinite loop problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have to manually limit the duration of the encoding with the `-t` option. Assuming your wave file is 20 seconds long, the command should look like this:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=5 -i response.wav -s 1980x1080 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -t 20.0 aNewVideo.mp4
```

To get the exact length of the wav file, simply run ffmpeg without any parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i response.wav
```

It will print something like this:

```
Input #0, wav, from 'response.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, bitrate: 704 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44000 Hz, mono, s16, 704 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the shortest flags to limit duration to audio length. The result will be a bit imprecise (video will be slightly longer)

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1920x1080:r=5 -i response.wav -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M -fflags +shortest aNewVideo.mp4`

Comment: Nice solution. I tried to solve this with filter options exclusively, but it seems it's not possible that way. The `shortest` amix option won't work if one of the input is an infinite source, even if the length of the lavfi source is limited to an arbitrary large number with the `duration`/`d` option...

Comment: Can't reproduce the failure of amix shortest featuring an unlimited lavfi source.

Comment: Strange. Anyways, here's what I tried (both `shortest` and `fist` does not do what you'd expect): `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=5 -i 15secaudio.wav -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000 -filter_complex '[1][2]amix=inputs=2:duration=first' -s 1980x1080 -c:a aac -b:a 128k aNewVideo.mp4`

Comment: shortest or first in amix will only limit the output from amix. The video has no duration limit. Add `-shortest` for that.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. The `-shortest` option makes the whole trickery with filtergraphs useless anyways, so yeah, it's not possible with filters.